# No obtengo todos los elementos de una lista sharepoint al realizar la consulta al API con Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

tengo una lista en sharepoint la cual por medio de Python la extraigo por medio del API de sharepoint. El código funciona ya que si obtengo datos al correrlo, pero me di cuenta que solo me obtiene alrededor de la mitad de los items de la lista, no he encontrado la razón del por qué me deja perdidos los demás items, he intentado con dos opciones de código obteniendo el mismo resultado, estos son mis dos códigos:

```
    import requests
    import json
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pyodbc
    
    client_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx'
    client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    tenant =  'xxxx'
    tenant_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx'  
    client_id = client_id + '@' + tenant_id
    
    data = {
        'grant_type':'client_credentials',
        'resource': "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/" + tenant + ".sharepoint.com@" + tenant_id, 
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
    }
    
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    
    url = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/" + tenant_id + "/tokens/OAuth/2"
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + json_data['access_token'],
        'Accept':'application/atom+xml',
        'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'
    }
    
    url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xx')/items"
    l = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(l.text)
```

y este es mi segundo código

```
    from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
    from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
    
    site_url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxx"
    sp_list = "xxxx"
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_client_credentials('xxx-xxx-xx', 'xxxxxxxxxx')
    sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
    s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(sp_list)
    l_items = s_list.get_items()
    ctx.load(l_items)
    ctx.execute_query()
    
    for item in l_items:
        print(item.properties['Title'])
```

No he entendido cuál error estoy cometiendo para solo traer una parte de items de la lista. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando la API es con graph la respuesta se devuelve con paginación si supera un número x de registros, el json antes de ingresar al "value" se tiene una propiedad que se llama @odata.nextlink que traerá el link de la página siguiente del mismo request, solo debes consultarla y si hay más esa respuesta te traerá el link de la siguiente página.

Te dejo documentación
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?tabs=http